# Docker Authentication required error when pulling image from dockerhub

Tags: docker, scrapy, dockerhub, scrapy-splash

I am on **Windows** and trying to pull spcrapy-splash base image with powershell.

Command is :
`docker pull scrapinghub/splash`

I have docker desktop running. And I did docker login and successfully logged in.

However every time I get this error on powershell: `docker: unauthorized: authentication required.`

[image]

I tried to modify .docker.config.json  file with

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "XXX", 
            "email": "email@gmail.com"
        }
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop",
    "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

I know auth is encoded username:password string. And I can login succesfully. So I cannot figure out why still keep getting authentication error. Is there something I am missing?

**Docker Version is 20.10.5**

Comment: Are you getting this error even after giving credentials?

Comment: yes still getting the same error

Comment: can you close the terminal and login again and try pulling the image

Comment: that didn't help unfortunately

Comment: May not be a solution, but what about clearing the credsStore and stackOrchestrator

Comment: Thanks just solved my problem by upgrading the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it was the Docker Desktop version problem. I Replaced latest with the current version and it worked.

[image]

For anyone who is struggling with authentication error, I suggest

check with the config file,

then update docker to the latest version.

Restart Docker and command line, run `docker login`

try again pulling or pushing.

Comment: Hi , I am facing the same issue while pulling an image.Shall i upgrade my docker version or docker desktop version or both.Please clarify

Comment: try to update docker desktop version first. Mine worked after that

Comment: That would mean downloading latest version from its official site,installing it(which would require admininistrative privilges which i dont have as its my official laptop).It can take days and i need kind of urgently to finish up a critical task

Answer (score -1):

The docker I am using is the latest Version 3.4.0 and I just downloaded it yesterday and installed it.
I tried installing splash using docker but it gave me authentication error.
I have opened the config, please what is the latest configuration arrangement that works for it ?

I have the auth, it's just to get the right arrangement to make it work.

Please can you send the configuration that worked for you ?

Comment: The answer section to a question is for solutions to a question, not asking for additional help. There is a small comment section under each Question where it would be more appropriate to put this type of request.